# Why does the object get stuck in the wall when repelled?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I made the endless movement of the object and its repulsion from the walls, but it does not always work correctly. At rounded corners (sometimes even at a straight wall), it just gets stuck and stops moving altogether, or moves slowly to the point where it stops moving. What can this be related to and how can it be fixed?

```cs
private void FixedUpdate() {
  rb.velocity = direction * normalSpeed;
  lastDirection = direction;
}

private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision) {
  //Repulsion from objects.
  direction = Vector3.Reflect(lastDirection.normalized, collision.GetContact(0).normal);
}
```

There is a small distance between the objects, but the circle seems to stick to the wall and moves with it until it collides with another collider:
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oQ8V0.png)

there are objects under the circle that also have colliders, but the collision between them is not considered, since they have the same layer (in the settings, I disabled the collision for objects on the same layer). What can be done to fix this error and what can it be related to?

The object in the general scale:

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4G0zJ.png)

I tried to increase the size of the wall collider, tried to change polygon collider to box collider, connect composite collider, changed the mechanics of the object movement (in these cases, the movement could work incorrectly), but the result was always the same - the jams (sticking to the wall) continued.

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to answer your question without having more information, but I can suggest if you are using physics to move your objects - utilize [physic materials](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-PhysicMaterial.html) and remove code that changes direction manually in OnCollisionEnter. Using physic materials you can easily make your object bounce from colliders of your choice without losing velocity.

Comment: Thank you, but I also need to change the speed of the object, even if it is moving at the moment, is it possible to implement it somehow in this case?

Comment: And I didn't seem to specify, but such jams occur at high speed of the mug

Comment: Well, if you are using physics to move your objects then it is best to rely on unity collision system and tweak variables on your rigid body, You can still keep the speed setting in the code, I am only talking about eliminating objects being stuck, I think it is happening because of your code inside OnCollisionEnter method.

Comment: Okay, I'll try to do it without specifying the direction in the code

Comment: I can't figure out how to get rid of reducing the speed of the circle when it collides with other objects.

Comment: See [physic materials](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-PhysicMaterial.html), you have to set bounciness to 1 in order to make objects bounce without any loss of energy. I assume in your case you would want to have:
dynamic friction = 0; 
static friction = 0; 
bounciness = 1;
Friction Combine = Minimum;
Bounce Combine = Maximum;

Comment: This is all good, of course, but dynamic friction, static friction and some other settings are only available in 3d mode, and I have physics material 2d. Only friction and bounciness are available here

Comment: Bounciness is what controls whether your object is losing speed or not after the collision. I recommend experimenting with numbers to figure out what you are looking for, all the variables are mentioned and explained in the documentation, if you are unsure what you need to change and why.

Comment: I set up the bounce and the circle pushes off as it should, but the movement is no longer infinite (it rises to a certain height and falls down, and disabling gravity also disables bounces), changing velocity to a certain one, the circle moves only in one direction and does not bounce off the walls, what can I do?

Comment: I realized a constant speed like this, but sooner or later it will start falling down anyway:

if (rb.velocity.magnitude > normalSpeed || rb.velocity.magnitude < normalSpeed)
        {
            rb.velocity = rb.velocity.normalized * normalSpeed;
        }

Comment: Small tip, better to use velocity.sqrMagnitude and normalSpeed*normalSpeed, it is much faster because square root operation is expensive, you should avoid doing it twice in the update loop if its not necessary. In your case you should constantly set velocity without if statement. Another solution would be to constantly add force, and use Vector3.ClampMagnitude to clamp magnitude of thr velocity.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try to do it, but apparently tomorrow)

Comment: If I understand you correctly, then everything should be like this:

rb.AddForce(normalSpeed * rb.velocity, Force Mode 2D.Impulse);
rb.velocity = Vector3.ClampMagnitude(rb.velocity, normalSpeed * normalSpeed);

But this way the object rises to a certain height and falls down. But it needs to move until it collides with something

Comment: Hi, `rb.AddForce(normalSpeed*rb.velocity, ForceMode2D.Impulse);` will not work. If you want constantly to add force to your object you have to use the direction of the object, for example, `transform.forward*normalSpeed` instead of `normalSpeed*rb.velocity`.